Exit Out of Blazor Submit Function based on Timer or Other Click Event
Blazor Server .NET 8.
What I want to achieve is that when a user clicks on a button, it calls a function that begins a process. I want the user to then click a different button that could stop that process before time runs out. However, my implementations block the UI for some reason.
<RadzenButton Size="ButtonSize.Medium"
              ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary"
              ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit"
              Text="Send"
              Icon="send"
              Click=@HandleValidSubmitAsync />

<RadzenButton Click=@Cancel Text="Cancel" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" />

code behind:
bool _cancelled { get; set; }


async void HandleValidSubmitAsync()
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();

    while (s.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(valFromAppSettings))
    {
      if (_cancelled ) return;
    }

   s.Stop();

  if (!_cancelled)
  {
    // do work
  }
}

void Cancel()
{
    _cancelled = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}

So after I click the button for HandleValidSubmitAsync and the timer starts, then I click Cancel, the Cancel button never hits the Cancel function, and therefore that while loop will never return out.
I hope this makes sense.

Yes this wont work your method is blocking and never gets the updated bool. You should read about cancellation tokens, that's what i think you are looking for.

It looks like you're trying to use a timer to return to the UI if the operation doesn't complete in X seconds.
In general that's not a good idea.  You leave the background process running, and an unpredictable outcome.  With a form submit: did it save, or didn't it?
Most modern async methods now take an optional cancellation token which you can use to apply control.
Here's a demo page showing how you use a cancellation token.  I've mocked the background async activity which accepts a cancellation token.
@page "/"
@using System.Text

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="m-2">
    <button disabled="@_running" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="this.Start">Start </button>
    <button hidden="@(!_running)" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="this.Stop">Stop</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>
        @_log.ToString()
    </pre>
</div>

@code {
    private StringBuilder _log = new();
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;
    private bool _running;

    private async Task Start()
    {
        _log.Clear();
        _cancellationTokenSource = new();
        await this.LongRunningTaskAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private async Task Stop()
    {
        if (_cancellationTokenSource is not null)
            await _cancellationTokenSource.CancelAsync();
        _log.AppendLine($"Stop requested at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
    }

    private async Task LongRunningTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _running = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            _log.AppendLine($"Working at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _log.AppendLine($"Cancellation accepted at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
                // can throw a cancellation exception here from the cancellation token    
                break;
            }
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        _running = false;
    }
}



Thank you for this. For the most part, this works, however, if you click Stop, the Task.Delay(1000) still needs to run its course before the thread opens up to be able to be restarted. The idea is that once stop is clicked, that long running task immediately stops processing, and then the user can immediately restart it without waiting the for the built in delay.

async void is a fire-and-forget pattern. The calling thread does not wait for the method to return.
For this to work, make it async Task and use a CancellationToken instead of the flag
